# When am adding a product to the cart, it's always appearing the last card productid

Tags: php, backend, cart

When am adding a product to the cart it's always appearing the last card productid. How can I resolve this error? It's not getting ID of the other product always getting last card product ID

Function for the card:

```
<?php
    function productlist($price,$product_name,$picture,$size,$productid)
    {
        $element ="
        <div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-6\" data-aos=\"fade-up\" data-aos-offset=\"200\" data-aos-delay=\"50\" data-aos-duration=\"1000\">  
        <div class=\"card card-border card-border cards-float card-hov card-height\" style=\"width: 18rem;\">
        <form method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
        <div class=\"inner\">
        <div class=\"view\">
                <a class=\"text-decoration-none\" href=\"product/large/$picture?>\">         
                <img class=\"card-img-top img-card \" src=\"product/large/$picture?></a>\" 
        </div>
     </div>
//add to cart button and wishlist button start from here
            <div id=\"mySidenav\" class=\"sidenav\">                                                               
            <button type=\"submit\" name=\"add_this\" id=\"about\"><i class=\"fa fa-heart-o align-baseline\"style=\"font-size:20px;\"></i> </button> 
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"product_id\" value='$productid'>                                    
            <button id=\"blog\"><i class=\"fa fa-shopping-cart\" style=\"font-size:20px\"></i></i> </button> 
            </div>]=
//add to cart button and wishlist button stop from here

            <div class=\"card-body\">
                <p class=\"card-text text-secondary\">$product_name  |$size|</p>
                <p class=\"card-text text-secondary\"></p>
                <h5>
                    <small><s class=\"text-secondary\"></s></small>
                    <span class=\"price\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\">$$price</span>
                </h5>
                <a href=\"checkout_page_1.php\" class=\"btn btn-light text-light card-btn\">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

       ";
       echo $element;

    }
   
?>
```

From a using a session am getting the product ID this code also in the index page

Product_id getting code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['add_this']))
 {
    //print_r($_POST['product_id']);
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    {
        print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
    }else
    {
        $item_array = array
        (
            'product_id'=>$_POST['product_id']
        );

        //creating a new session variable
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]=$item_array;
        print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
    }
 }
```

Card function calling code in index page:

```
   <?php 
         $result = $database->getData();

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            productlist($row['price'], $row['product_name'], $row['picture'], $row['size'], $row ['pro_id']);
         }
            ?>
```

Comment: Have you verified what values are being sent to the `productList()` function in the `while()` loop?